# Grails ant tasks don't work - Unable to start Grails: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: grails, ant, taskdef

I'm having issues getting something which seems very basic running with Grails. I want to call grails commands from an Ant script - Grails provides a Grails task to achieve this. I have defined the Grails taskdef and classpaths as per the docs however, no matter what command I call I get the same error...

```
grails-compile:
   [grails] Resolving dependencies...
   [grails] Dependencies resolved in 1192ms.

BUILD FAILED
/java/grailstest/build.xml:22: Unable to start Grails: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Even when I create a new Grails app using 'grails create-app' and then run the integrate ant command 'grails integrate-with --ant' to generate a default build.xml, I get the same error when running any of the tasks in the generated build.xml.

I've tested this with Grails 1.3.1, 1.3.4 and 1.3.5 and am getting the same error.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? There must be something stupid I'm doing wrong or this would never have made it out the door of the Grails factory... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to mention that I am using Ant version 1.8.1. I have just discovered that switching back to Ant 1.7.1 'solves' this problem but this is not really ideal as I need 1.8.1 for other build tasks. I'll submit a bug on the Grails issue tracker as it seems a lot of people are having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the same issue. It seems that Ant 1.8 is not supported yet (but Ant 1.7 is), see [GRAILS-6897](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/6499). Some users have complained that the documentation does not state it strictly.